# Error:list index out of range in my loop?

Tags: python

The question is: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

I am getting an `error: list index out of range`. I think its a problem with my for loop, but I don't understand why this code won't run. How can I resolve this?

```
def sum13(nums):
  unlucky = False
  if sum(nums) == 0:
   return 0
  for num in nums:
   x = 0
   if nums[x] == 13:
    unlucky = True
    break
   x += 1
  if unlucky == True:
    return sum(nums) - 13 - nums[x+1]
  if unlucky == False:
    return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this statement

```
if unlucky == True:
    return sum(nums) - 13 - nums[x+1]
```

Its possible that the last number is 13, in which case `nums[x+1]` would give you the error.

Instead, use the condition

```
if unlucky == True:
    return sum(nums[:x+1]) - 13
```

Comment: @thornbird Cool. If that helped, don't forget to [accept and upvote the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: I think the index error is raised for nums = [13] only.

Comment: @Petruz No, the error will be raised for nums = [1, 13], nums = [1, 2, 13],  nums = [..., 13] and so on. The last number has to be 13.

Comment: nums[x+1]  will always be nums[1] since x = 0. I only get an index error with nums = [13] and there is no index error with [..,..13] since there exists a nums[1].

Comment: X is reset to 0 within the loop and the loop breaks with x being 0.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, how you can do this is to loop over until the number (but not including) the number is 13, - this'll save the checking lucky/unlucky and the deduction of the unlucky number, as well as possible index errors, eg:

```
def sum13(nums):
    total = 0
    for num in nums:
        if num == 13:
            break
        total += num
    return total
```

Or using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def sum13(nums):
    until_13 = takewhile(lambda num: num != 13, nums)
    return sum(until_13)
```

You could also use `list.index` to find a value of 13, and then sum to that index, eg:

```
def sum13(nums):
    try:
        end = nums.index(13)
    except ValueError:
        end = None
    return sum(nums[:end])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=range(20)
l1=l[:12]
l2=l[13:]
l1.extend(l2)
res=sum([y for y in l1 if y!=13])
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the list index out of range for `nums = [13]` only, because this block will render `x = 0` if 13 is in `nums`:

```
for num in nums:
  x = 0
  if nums[x] == 13:
   unlucky = True
   break
 x += 1
```

Therefore `nums[x+1]` will be out of range for `nums = [13]`.

Another problem is that the code does not suffice in nums that contains 13 several times. This adjustment of your code would:

```
def sum123(nums):
    t = 0
    unlucky = True
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 13:
            unlucky = False
        elif unlucky == False and nums[i] != 13:
            unlucky = True        
        else:
            t += nums[i]
    return t
```